# MsTest /category:"group1&group2" does not work

Tags: mstest

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx#category

**/category:"group1&group2" runs tests that are in both test categories "group1" and "group2." Tests that are only in one of the specified test categories will not be run.**

This filter type '&' does not work for me! I can successfully use /category:"group1|group2" as a workaround.

But has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Are you sure you have tests that belong on both test categories? Can you post a test mothod that contains them both and the command you run?

Comment: You are correct. My tests do not belong to both categories. So the filter | is correct for me.